# TSQL - CTE/#Temp Table

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

In SSMS 2016 I have created a CTE and then immediately after the statement, I delete some rows from the CTE.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT [GroupID], [UserID]+0.5, [Value] from dbo.myTable
)

DELETE FROM cte WHERE concat(GroupID, UserID) in (select concat(GroupID, UserID) as Concat from cte group by GroupID)
```

However, I want to then `INSERT` the remaining rows into the existing table, but when I try, I get the following error: "`Invalid object name 'cte'.`"

I suspect the issue has something to do with the way CTEs work. As I am fairly new to them, I'm not sure, but it seems like a CTE can only be referenced once immediately following the `WITH AS`? Is that true? Is there a way around this? How can I insert data from the CTE?

I was thinking about using a temp table somehow, but I don't know if there's really a difference.

Comment: Is that really what you want to do? Why not just update? Why do you even need a cte for this?  That is not valid syntax.

Comment: If you are targeting the same table you might use a CTE in connection with MERGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cte's are one and done. You run one query with them and then they go away. You can use a temp table instead and that will persist for the duration of your session.

```
SELECT [GroupID], [UserID], [Value] 
INTO #temp 
from dbo.myTable

DELETE FROM #temp 
WHERE concat(GroupID, UserID) in (select concat(GroupID, UserID) as Concat from #temp group by GroupID)

INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

As for the high level diff's between cte's and temp tables. Temp tables are physical storage and you can index them. CTE's are named subqueries and not stored as tabled/objects.

Comment: I see, guess I will give this a try then :)

Comment: Not correct.  CTE is just syntax.   It is not run and stored.